# Admin access to AWS console, but no access via CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, authentication, terraform, command-line-interface, aws-cli

I use a few different acounts and keep all the credentials in ~/.aws/credentials. CLI works fine on all other accounts, so it's not a configuration issue. The only taht works is `aws sts get-caller-identity`.

The strange thing is that I belong to the Administrator group (as does everyone for now) and none of us have CLI access, despite having access keys and full Admin permissions.

I though it's because of MFA, but I use another account with MFA just fine through CLI. There's also this policy on the account (but it doesn't look restrictive?):

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": [
        "iam:ListAccountAliases",
        "iam:ListUsers",
        "iam:GetAccountSummary",
        "iam:GetAccountPasswordPolicy"
      ],
      "Resource": "*",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Sid": "AllowAllUsersToListAccounts"
    },
    {
      "Action": [
        "iam:ChangePassword",
        "iam:CreateLoginProfile",
        "iam:DeleteLoginProfile",
        "iam:GetLoginProfile",
        "iam:ListAccessKeys",
        "iam:UpdateLoginProfile",
        "iam:ListSigningCertificates",
        "iam:ListSSHPublicKeys",
        "iam:GetSSHPublicKey",
        "iam:UploadSSHPublicKey",
        "iam:DeleteSSHPublicKey"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:iam::____________:user/${aws:username}"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Sid": "AllowIndividualUserToSeeAndManageTheirOwnAccountInformation"
    },
    {
      "Action": [
        "iam:ListVirtualMFADevices",
        "iam:ListMFADevices"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:iam::____________:mfa/*",
        "arn:aws:iam::____________:user/${aws:username}"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Sid": "AllowIndividualUserToListTheirOwnMFA"
    },
    {
      "Action": [
        "iam:CreateVirtualMFADevice",
        "iam:RequestSmsMfaRegistration",
        "iam:FinalizeSmsMfaRegistration",
        "iam:EnableMFADevice",
        "iam:ResyncMFADevice"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:iam::____________:mfa/${aws:username}",
        "arn:aws:iam::____________:user/${aws:username}"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Sid": "AllowIndividualUserToManageTheirOwnMFA"
    }
  ]
}
```

What could it be?

Comment: What do you mean by "no CLI access"? Please provide some examples.

Comment: getting errors like `An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the ListBuckets operation: Access Denied` or `AccessDenied: User: arn:aws:iam::______:user/username is not authorized to perform: iam:ListAccountAliases on resource: * with an explicit deny
 status code: 403`

Comment: There is no concept of "no CLI access". The AWS CLI is a Python program that uses the AWS SDK for Python (boto3) to make API calls. Each API call is assessed individually when received by AWS. The above error is saying that the user is not allowed to list Amazon S3 buckets, which would be accurate because the policy you provided does not grant any permissions for Amazon S3. However, the policy _does_ grant permission such that you should be able to use `aws iam list-account-aliases`, which suggests that the AWS CLI is not using the credentials that you are expecting.

Comment: Thank you! I checked the credentials couple of times and regenerated access keys - still no difference. But I can change accounts at will and no other account is causing similar issues.

Answer (score 0):

There is no concept of "no CLI access". The AWS CLI is a Python program that uses the AWS SDK for Python (boto3) to make API calls. Each API call is assessed individually when received by AWS.

The error message you provided is saying that the user is not allowed to list Amazon S3 buckets, which would be accurate because the policy you provided does not grant any permissions for Amazon S3.

The other error mentions an `explicit deny` -- so either it is *not* using the policy you have listed, or a [Service control policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/organizations/latest/userguide/orgs_manage_policies_scps.html) is in force, which is limiting the API calls that are permitted.

Comment: There is no access at all from outside of the console, except for `aws sts get-caller-identity`. Also, there are two policies attached to my account, the one provided in my question and the Administrator access: `{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "*",
      "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
}`

Comment: Could SCP deny access from outside of the console while also giving me full admin rights in the console?

Comment: No, behaviour would be identical. Does the result of `get-caller-identity` match the IAM User who is logged into the console?

Comment: Yes, it does match the user